# Perforce, adding files with wildcards in them from the P4V interface

Tags: perforce

Is it possible to add files with wildcards to the depot from the P4V interface. The files allow them to be added using the -f flag but I cant find how to add that in P4V.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; right-click the file(s) and "Mark for Add".

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4v/Content/P4V/files.add.html

You'll see the "filenames contain wildcards" warning in the log pane, and then P4V will show a confirmation dialog to ask whether you want to add the files anyway.  Say yes, and the files are now open for add.